# Powershell Get Users that are NOT in multiple Azure AD Group

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I am trying to get a list of users that are NOT in multiple Azure AD Groups. I tried different scripts from the internet but then find out that the list is not complete. The code that i tried:

```
$users = Get-AzureADUser -All $true -Filter "accountEnabled eq true" | Where UserPrincipalName -like '*@company.com'

#list of groups by ObjectID that you want to check if users are NOT a member of
$groupids = @("662627b7-f1bd-4683-819d-36d299e19308", "9080a490-481b-4f7f-9d26-ecf7a186b00d", "3c3a6682-91bf-4afc-8634-7b54999e98b8") 

#create hashtable that will contain users
$userht = @{} 
Get-AzureADUser -Filter "accountEnabled eq true" | Where UserPrincipalName -like '*@irdeto.com' | ForEach-Object { $userht.Add($_.ObjectId, $_) } #add all AzureAD users to hashtable with ObjectID as unique key

ForEach ($id  in  $groupids) {
    #if user is member of group, remove them from hashtable
    Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $id | foreach-object { $userht.Remove($_.ObjectId) } 
}

#return remaining users that are not in specified groups
$userht.Values
```

When I run this i found a few users that are non in the groups but i also still found a lot of users manually that are not in the group and was not in the outcome of the script.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want to remove/exclude users that are a member of _any_ of the groups, or do you want to remove/exclude users that are a member of _2 or more_ of the groups?

Comment: I want to get a list of the users that are not in any of the 3 groups.

Answer (score 0):

Tried with your Powershell script getting all the user which have unique `DIsplayName` and `Mail` .

**Note : Make Sure Every User should have unique `DisplayName` and `Mail`. If two user have same DisplayName or Mail it will count as one.**

Example : I have total 44 users in AAD and 6 user added in 3 group (each having 2)

After running above script i am getting 36 count but expected is 38. But due to two user have same DisplayName and Mail it counted as one.

[image]

[image]

[image]